# Excel vlookup multiple values and add duplicate rows

Tags: r, excel, vlookup, vba

I have two spreadsheets that looks like this:
I know if I start with Spreadsheet2, I can just vlookup and get the values.
But I need to start with Spreadsheet1. I need to Add rows. This is a small data but what I actually have is huge..(more than 20000 rows).

Spreadsheet1:

```
Category    Type    NumItem
Air         B747    10
Ground      TBus1   15
Air         B777    20
Air         A380    5
```

Spreadsheet2:

```
Type    TypeElement    NumEngine
B747    747T1          2
B747    747T2          4
B747    747T3          8
Tbus1   TbusT1         0
B777    777T1          6
B777    777T2          4
A380    380T1          10
```

I want to merge these to spreadsheet. As you can see Type for both match, but for each type I have multiple "TypeElement"s.

I want it to look something like

```
Category    Type    NumItem    TypeElement    NumEngine
Air         B747    10         747T1          2
Air         B747    10         747T2          4
Air         B747    10         747T3          8
Ground      TBus1   15         TbusT1         0
Air         B777    20         777T1          6
Air         B777    20         777T2          4
Air         A380    5          380T1          10
```

Can this be done using functions in Excel or.. do I have to use VBA/Macro?
IF anyone knows how this can be done using R, please comment what formulas/packages I should use.

Thank you!!

Comment: There are several libraries that can import/export from Excel: openxlsx, XLConnect. Use them to read both spreadsheets into two data frames, and then use `merge`

Comment: The reason why I have to start with Spreadsheet 1 is because I need to find out which items in Spreadsheet1 doesn't have any corresponding data in Spreadsheet2. For instance, if there is B700 in Spreadsheet1, Spreadsheet2 does not have any, which I can find blank/error cells.

Comment: You don't have to use a spreadsheet for that (and if you have 20k rows, you don't want to). Import into R with `readxl` or your favorite package, then use `merge` (here with `all = TRUE`), or if that gets confusing, the dplyr package's `*_join` functions (here `full_join`), which are SQL-style. Also note that you have inconsistencies between `TBus1` and `Tbus1`, so you may want to take everything `toupper` or `tolower`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @r-schifini mentioned, there are several libraries you can use to import Excel files.  Here I use the `readxl` package.  To retain all rows from the first spreadsheet -- your Spreadsheet1 -- specify `all.x=TRUE` in the `merge` function. See `?merge` for more details.  Note that I've added one more row in Spreadsheet1 with fake data for type `B700`.

```
library(readxl)
ss1 <- read_excel(path = "spreadsheet1.xlsx", sheet = 1)
ss2 <- read_excel(path = "spreadsheet2.xlsx", sheet = 1)


out <- merge(ss1, ss2, all.x=TRUE)
out
#    Type Category NumItem TypeElement NumEngine
# 1  A380      Air       5       380T1        10
# 2  B700      Air       8        <NA>        NA
# 3  B747      Air      10       747T1         2
# 4  B747      Air      10       747T2         4
# 5  B747      Air      10       747T3         8
# 6  B777      Air      20       777T1         6
# 7  B777      Air      20       777T2         4
# 8 TBus1   Ground      15        <NA>        NA
```

Why do we have `NA`s in row 8?  It's because your type is `TBus1` in Spreadsheet1, and `Tbus1` in Spreadsheet2.  To circumvent problems like this, we can change the case to upper before we do the merge.

```
ss1$Type <- toupper(ss1$Type)
ss2$Type <- toupper(ss2$Type)
out <- merge(ss1, ss2, all.x=TRUE)
out
#    Type Category NumItem TypeElement NumEngine
# 1  A380      Air       5       380T1        10
# 2  B700      Air       8        <NA>        NA
# 3  B747      Air      10       747T1         2
# 4  B747      Air      10       747T2         4
# 5  B747      Air      10       747T3         8
# 6  B777      Air      20       777T1         6
# 7  B777      Air      20       777T2         4
# 8 TBUS1   Ground      15      TbusT1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas
1) you could try combining the rows and using the sort function, sorting the valued by ascending or descending values in the element item. For instance, do a custom sort or filter.

2) you have to pick how you want to categorizembrace the values. By category? By type? There's some way you can group the items natively. To set links between the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I use VBA moving your tb1 and tb2 to a Access file (c:\testdb.mdb).
Then using SQL command to join them

```
Sub Main()
    Dim adoxCat As Object, adoConn As Object, adoRst As Object, var As Variant, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Long

'make an empty mdb file'
    If Dir("C:\testdb.mdb") = "" Then
        Set adoxCat = CreateObject("ADOX.catalog")
        adoxCat.Create "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\testdb.mdb;"
        Set adoxCat = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "C:\testdb.mdb is existed.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
'create an ADO connection'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set adoConn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    With adoConn
        .Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\testdb.mdb;"
        If .State  1 Then
            MsgBox "Cannot create ADO Connection.", vbCritical
            Set adoConn = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
'create two Tables in the mdb file.'
    With adoConn
        .Execute "CREATE TABLE tb_1 (Category varchar, Type varchar, NumItem number)"
        .Execute "CREATE TABLE tb_2 (Type varchar, TypeElement varchar, NumEngine number)"

'move data in excel to mdb file'
        var = toArray(Worksheets(1))
        For i = LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1)
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_1 (category, type, NumItem) VALUES("
            strSQL = strSQL & " '" & var(i, 0) & "',"
            strSQL = strSQL & " '" & var(i, 1) & "',"
            strSQL = strSQL & "  " & var(i, 2) & " );"
            .Execute strSQL
        Next i

        var = toArray(Worksheets(2))
        For i = LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1)
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_2 (Type, TypeElement, NumEngine) VALUES("
            strSQL = strSQL & " '" & var(i, 0) & "',"
            strSQL = strSQL & " '" & var(i, 1) & "',"
            strSQL = strSQL & "  " & var(i, 2) & " );"
            .Execute strSQL
        Next i 

'Use SQL Join statement to Join two tables'
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_1 left join tb_2 on tb_1.type = tb_2.type;"
        Set adoRst = .Execute(strSQL)
'output the result to excel worksheet(3)'
        Worksheets(3).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset adoRst

        .Close
    End With
    Set adoConn = Nothing
'remove the mdb file'
    Kill "c:\testdb.mdb" 
End Sub


Function toArray(from_WSht As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim strPath As String, myRng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, dt As Variant

    Set myRng = from_WSht.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    If not myRng.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoTo errHdr
        ReDim dt(myRng.Rows.Count - 1, myRng.Columns.Count - 1) As Variant
        i = 0
        For Each rw In myRng.Rows
            If rw.Row > 1 Then
                j = 0
                For Each c In rw.Cells
                    dt(i, j) = c.Value
                    j = j + 1
                Next c
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next rw

    toArray = dt
    Exit Function
errHdr:
    toArray = 0
End Function
```

[image]